# Woocommerce shop page don't display one category in WPML

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wpml

I have a site https://marvelpit.sk/en/products/ based on wordpress with woocommerce and WPML.

There are 4 main product categories. When I switch the RU version, the "Electric actuators" category is not displayed. I am sure, that everything is OK in wp-admin, each product has translation EN and RU, product categories also.

Do anyone guess, why the category is not displayed in RU version?

Comment: You may get a better, more specialised answer over on the Wordpress StackExchange: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Shane Wrong! Woocommerce or Wpml tagged questions are off topic on Wordpress StackExchange. So you should remove that comment please.

Comment: @user11344866 For related WPML questions, you should better ask a question in WPML support pages.